# Connect existing MySQL database in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

I want to connect my Ruby on Rails application with a MySQL database, which was developed separately. For this connection I used the
`development` environment:

```
adapter: mysql
username: root  
password: ******  
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3306
```

When I try to make the MySQL connection in Rails it shows:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:4:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.5.9. (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from D:/registration/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

D:\registration>
```

Also, when I try my rake command it shows:

```
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.5.9.
D:/registration/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/registration/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

D:\registration>
```

How can I connect to my database?

Answer (score 2):

As per the error it seems like you are using a newer version of the gem than your MySQL client.

It says:

- Your gem has been compiled (created with) my sql client version 6.0.0.
- Your actual my sql client version (in your machine) is 5.5.9.

Could you post your MySQL gem version as well as your MySQL client version?

Upgrating your MySQL client to version 6.0.0 should fix this issue.